# Has Mary Jane Watson ever deviated from her standard appearance?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, spider-man

MJ typically appears with striking red hair

[image]

Has she ever had any noticeable changes to her appearance in the last 50-ish years?

Comment: If the rumour that Zendaya is playing Mary Jane Watson in the upcoming *Spider-Man: Homecoming* ends up being true, then maybe... but then again, I'm guessing that is what motivated this question in the first place.

Comment: In Spider-Man: The New Animated Series  Mary Jane have short hair if it counts.

Comment: My first instinct is that this question is intended to make sure his rant later is entirely factual.

Comment: @Amadeus9 its always best to have sources for your rant :P

Comment: Of course this doesn't preclude a red-haired MJ in Homecoming... http://howtobearedhead.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/redhead_ethnic_how_to_be_a_redhead6.jpg

Comment: @user36790 sounds like fair game type up an answer if you want

Comment: Is there any way I can improve my answer?

Comment: @DrRDizzle... don't go there, man. Just... don't.

Answer (score 36):

### Two adaptations portray her without red hair.

- [*Supaidāman*](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Supaid%C4%81man_(TV_series)#Season_1)

[image]

[Hitomi Sakuma](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hitomi_Sakuma_(Earth-51778)) is *Supaidāman*'s version of Mary Jane.

- *[Spider-Man: Turn off the Dark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Turn_Off_the_Dark)*

Mary Jane was portrayed by several actresses in this musical, one of whom, [Rebecca Faulkenberry](http://www.broadway.com/shows/spider-man-turn-off-the-dark/photos/spider-man-turn-off-the-dark-show-photos/170471/show-photos-spider-man-turn-off-the-dark-rebecca-faulkenberry), had brown hair.

[image]

There's also a universe where Mary Jane is an anthropomorphic [water buffalo](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mary_Jane_Waterbuffalo_(Earth-8311)), but she retains her red hair.

[image]

Comment: Spider-Ham!...yay...

Comment: +1 Never knew there was a Japanese adaptation of Spider-Man

Comment: Because why wouldn't the guys on SciFi SE know about that time someone was turned into a Water Buffalo.

Comment: And this is why we get so many WEIRD questions!! Because half the time... someone really does know the answer!

Comment: Obligatory: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltG37Bbx1qk

Comment: "_There's also a universe where Mary Jane is an anthropomorphic water buffalo_" Is one of my new favourite sentences.

Comment: Is that the same universe where spiderman is a **cape** buffalo? I'll see myself out..

Comment: Eeeevvvrrybody 's got a water buffalo. Yours is fast but mine is slow. Where we got 'em I don't know but ev'rybody 's got a water buffalo...

Comment: @NexTerren Where's my water buffalo? Why don't I have a water buffalo?

Comment: The Supaidāman example is irrelevant, really. That character wasn't intended to be Mary Jane Watson at all, she was just the girlfriend of the main protagonist (who wasn't even Peter Parker). She wasn't a model, wasn't sultry, and wasn't characterized anything like Mary Jane. In fact, the only real connection is the gender and relationship to a guy wearing the Spider-man suit. The water buffalo example, though... that one's completely on point.

Answer (score 33):

## In the Comics

By mistake in Daredevil #77 ([**Source**](http://scans-daily.dreamwidth.org/4060892.html?thread=134774492&s2id=100963&style=light))

[image]

> Mary Jane Watson with blonde hair (and Peter Parker with black hair).
>
> And yes, this issue of Daredevil was published BEFORE Gwen Stacy died. (This issue is cover dated as June 1971. Gwen died two years later in Amazing Spider-Man #121, cover dated June 1973.)

Other than that, the red hair has been a defining characteristic (although it has changed *styles* many times)....even in other Marvel universes....and when she's been completely transformed into, say, the Demogoblin [Earth-1610]

[image]

**[ComicVine](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/mary-jane/4005-13380/)**

Comment: I'm guessing Demogoblin doesn't use the word "Tiger"...

Comment: When female characters transform into non-human humanoids, why do they so often look masculine (flat muscular chest etc.)?

Comment: Maybe the humanoids are not mammalian and therefore do not need/have mammary glands and so they do not have bosoms...

Comment: Similarly, I'm sure there are lots of women with rather muscular chests its just not so obvious beneath the layers of fatty tissue. (A bit like my "six pack".)

Answer (score 5):

Well, on [Himarm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/29220/himarm)'s advice, I am turning my comment as an answer:

In *Ultimate Spider-Man vs the Sinister 6* - S4E15 named [*Symbiote Saga: Part 3*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5874250/), Mary Jane Watson was transformed into  *Carnage Queen*.

Below are the pics on how MJ turned to *Carnage Queen*:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, below is the pic where a mutated Morbius tried to control *Carnage Queen* by putting a yellow-colored mind-control device on her head:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mary Jane briefly sported a short, curly hairdo in the late '60s.

[Spectacular Spider-Man Magazine Vol 1 2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spectacular_Spider-Man_Magazine_Vol_1_2)

[image]

I suspect this might've had something to do with the fact that Gwen Stacy had recently altered her hairstyle to more closely resemble MJ's, so this was possibly an attempt to make them look less similar. It didn't stick though, since MJ quickly reverted to her original hairstyle.

[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #48](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_48)

[image]

When Todd McFarlane took over the pencilling duties on Amazing Spider-Man in the late '80s, he decided to draw MJ with bigger, curlier hair, and this look stuck through to the early and mid '90s, although by the late '90s, she reverted to her original hairstyle again.

[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #326](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_326)

[image]